# Need to comment to a disappeared answer

Tags: feature-request, answers

@D.W.

I asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/85951/39512).

The user D.W. answered. Then I found a bug in his answer. Then I commented that I apparently know how to fix the bug (without thorough rewriting everything).

But then D.W. deleted his answer. He probably haven't read my next comment carefully.

As such I propose to allow the questioner to view deleted answers to his question, for situations like this, so that the questioner could be able to contact the answerer even if the answer is deleted.

Fortunately I have restored the deleted answer from Google cache: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Automatic_transformation_of_XML_namespaces/Implementation/Precedences/Old_answer

That I need to use Google cache indicates a problem. It should be solved within StackExchange, without resorting to hacks like Google cache.

Comment: FWIW, the line of commentary reads, to me, as if D.W. does not think your proposed fix works, and that he didn't find a fix himself. I don't think he would have deleted had he thought the answer salvagable, or even of educational value in its wrongness.

Comment: @Raphael 1. What is "the line of commentary"? Why do you assume that D.W. has really read my next comment, just not overlooked it not reading?

Comment: 1) As a mod, I can still see the deleted answer and the comments on it. 2) Because I've experienced D.W. around the site for a few years and have known him to be quite diligent. He said he'd reconsider the answer and delete it if he thought it was wrong; that's what I assume he did. Counter-question: why do *you* assume foul play? 3) Enough from me; I'm sure D.W. will speak up once the wheel of timezones turns his way.

Comment: Cautionary note: recall that we're all volunteering our free time here. Nobody is entitled to receive an answer. Might seem obvious but is important to keep in mind.

Comment: Oh dear.  I hope that this didn't cause too much inconvenience.  As you correctly pointed out, my answer was flawed.  I couldn't convince myself that your proposed fix was enough to fix the problem, I didn't have enough time to study the problem more thoroughly, and I didn't want to leave an incorrect answer.  For instance, I didn't want others to think your question has been answered and prevent someone else from answering your question -- that'd be a shame, as I found your question fascinating and worthy of careful study.  Sorry that this made it hard to find the old answer.

Comment: @D.W. Have you concluded (why?) that my fix seems not enough or just didn't check if it's enough?

Comment: I tried checking but couldn't convince myself either way (couldn't find a proof that it was enough; couldn't find an example to demonstrate that it's not enough).  I'm worried it will generate extra relationships that aren't implied by your condition, but I don't know if that worry is well-founded.  Basically, I just don't know.